# Assertion error with snakemq python 3.2.1

Tags: python, assertion

I'm working through the tutorial found here:
http://www.snakemq.net/doc/tutorial.html

Here is my code:

```
import snakemq.link
import snakemq.packeter
import snakemq.messaging
import snakemq.message

#Build Stack

my_link = snakemq.link.Link()
my_packeter = snakemq.packeter.Packeter(my_link)
my_messaging = snakemq.messaging.Message("tyler", "", my_packeter)

#Tyler

my_link.add_listener(("", 4000))
my_link.add_connector(("localhost", 4001))

#Sally

my_link.add_connector(("localhost", 4000))
my_link.add_connector(("localhost", 4001))

#Paul

my_link.add_connector(("localhost", 4000))
my_link.add_listener(("", 4001))

#Run link loop (it drives the whole stack)

my_link.loop()

#Tyler wants to send a message to Sally
#drop after 30 seconds if the message can't be delivered

message = snakemq.message.Message(b"Hello", ttl = 600)
my_messaging.send_message("Sally", message)

#receiving callback

def on_recv(conn, ident, message):
    print(ident, message)

my_messaging.on_message_recv.add(on_recv)
```

I receive the error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "C:/Users/Owner/Desktop/snakemq tutorial/test.py", line 10, in
>    my_messaging = snakemq.messaging.Message("tyler", "",
>   my_packeter)
>   File "C:\Python32\lib\site-packages\snakemq-1.2-py3.2.egg\snakem\message.py",
>     line 30, in **init** assert type(data) == bytes
>     AssertionError

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are building the `Message` incorrectly.

According to the doc, http://www.snakemq.net/doc/api/messaging.html#message, the constructor is

```
class snakemq.message.Message(data, ttl=0, flags=0, uuid=None)
```

But in this line,

```
my_messaging = snakemq.messaging.Message("tyler", "", my_packeter)
```

you are passing `"tyler"`, `""` and `my_packeter` which do not match the function definition.

You should try this

```
my_messaging = snakemq.messaging.Message(b"tyler")
```

Comment: I made the suggested changes Anthony and now iI get this error:

'''Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Owner\Desktop\snakemq tutorial\test.py", line 20, in <module>
    my_link.add_connector(("localhost", 4001))
  File "C:\Python32\lib\site-packages\snakemq-1.2-py3.2.egg\snakemq\link.py", line 297, in add_connector
    raise ValueError("connector '%r' already set", address)
ValueError: ("connector '%r' already set", ('127.0.0.1', 4001))'''

Comment: If my answer has solved your question, you should accept the answer. The new exception is totally different from original problem. You should post a new question.